# N-dimensional tree, any OO language

Tags: php, algorithm, oop, recursion, tree

I need N-dimensional(limited to N descendants per node) tree with left-to-right filling.

Something like that(pseudo-vardump):

```
// before
TreeNode {
  children [
    TreeNode {
      children [TreeNode {}, TreeNode {}, TreeNode {}]
    },
    TreeNode {
      children [null, null, null]
    },
    TreeNode {
      children [null, null, null]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then add node, and I should have after that:

```
// after
TreeNode {
  children [
    TreeNode {
      children [TreeNode {}, TreeNode {}, TreeNode {}]
    },
    TreeNode {
      children [TreeNode {}, null, null]
    },
    TreeNode {
      children [null, null, null]
    }
  ]
}
```

Things I've done:

```
<?php

class TreeNode
{
    const NODE_CHILDREN_MAX = 3;
    const NODE_CHILD_LEVELS_MAX = 6;

    protected $id;

    private $data;

    private $parent;

    private $children = [];

    private $weight = 0;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set weight
     *
     * @param integer $weight
     * @return TreeNode
     */
    public function setWeight($weight)
    {
        $this->weight = $weight;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get weight
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getWeight()
    {
        return $this->weight;
    }

    public function setData($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param TreeNode $parent
     * @return TreeNode
     */
    public function setParent(TreeNode $parent = null)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return TreeNode
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * Add children
     *
     * @param TreeNode $node
     * @return TreeNode[]
     */
    public function addChild(TrinarNode $node)
    {
        if (count($this->children) < static::NODE_CHILDREN_MAX) {
            $this->children[] = $node;
            $node->setParent($this);
            $this->weight++;
            return [$this, $node];
        } else {

            $children = $this->children;
            /** @var TreeNode[] $children */
            $children = $this->children;
            usort($children, function (TreeNode $node1, TreeNode $node2) {
                $levelDifference = $node1->subtractLevel($node2);
                $sorting = ($node1->weight - $node2->weight) % 2;
                if (abs($levelDifference) == 1) {
                    $sorting = -$sorting;
                }
                if ($sorting === 0) {
                    $sorting = ($node1->id - $node2->id) % 2;
                }
                return $sorting;
            });
            foreach ($children as $childNode) {
                $this->weight++;
                return array_merge($childNode->addChild($node), [$this]);
            }
            return [];
        }
    }

    private function subtractLevel(TreeNode $node)
    {
        return $this->getChildLevelCount() - $node->getChildLevelCount();
    }

    private function getMaxDifference()
    {
        $logs = array_map(function (TreeNode $node) {
            return floor(log($node->getWeight() === 0 ? 1 : $node->getWeight(), self::NODE_CHILDREN_MAX));
        }, $this->children);
        return pow(
            self::NODE_CHILDREN_MAX,
            min($logs) + 1
        );
    }

    public static function getLevelCount($level)
    {
        if ($level === 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return pow(self::NODE_CHILDREN_MAX, $level) + self::getLevelCount($level - 1);
    }

    public function hasEmptyNodes()
    {
        return count($this->children) < self::NODE_CHILDREN_MAX;
    }

    /**
     * Get children
     *
     * @return TreeNode[]
     */
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    public function getChildLevelCount()
    {
        $weight = $this->weight;
        if (!$weight) {
            return 0;
        }
        return floor(log($weight, self::NODE_CHILDREN_MAX)) + 1;
    }

    private function getLevelBreakCount()
    {
        return count(array_unique(array_map(function (TreeNode $node) {
            return $node->getChildLevelCount();
        }, $this->children)));
    }
}
```

Current problem is that I don't how to decide which node should be chosen on addition... In previous version nodes were added based on weight(least weight should be chosen) but it is not what I exactly need. I need to add nodes from left to right while "level" not ended and if "level" is full create new one. Where "level" - group of nodes which are in same distance from root node.

Previous version(for clarity):

```
// before
TreeNode {
  children [
    TreeNode {
      children [TreeNode {}, null, null]
    },
    TreeNode {
      children [null, null, null]
    },
    TreeNode {
      children [null, null, null]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then add node:

```
// after
TreeNode {
  children [
    TreeNode {
      children [TreeNode {}, null, null]
    },
    TreeNode {
      children [TreeNode {}, null, null]
    },
    TreeNode {
      children [null, null, null]
    }
  ]
}
```

And unit-test that `TreeNode` should pass(*PHPUnit* required):

```
<?php

class TestableTreeNode extends TreeNode
{
    private $name;

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }
}

class TreeNodeTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $flatStorage = [];

    public function test()
    {
        $this->iniSet('memory_limit', -1);
        $data = $this->generateTestData(3);
        $testable = $this->flatten($data->real);
        $this->dump('expected.dump', $data->flat);
        $this->dump('real.dump', $data->real);
        $this->dump('converted.dump', $testable);
        foreach ($data->flat as $levelNumber => $level) {
            $this->assertArrayHasKey($levelNumber, $testable, 'Searched level doesn\'t exists!');
            $testableLevel = $testable[$levelNumber];
            foreach ($level as $nodeId => $node) {
                $this->assertArrayHasKey($nodeId, $testableLevel, 'Searched node doesn\'t exists!');
                $testableNode = $testableLevel[$nodeId];
                $this->assertEquals($node->getName(), $testableNode->getName(), 'Tree is not valid!');
            }
        }
    }

    protected function generateTestData($levels = TestableTreeNode::NODE_CHILD_LEVELS_MAX)
    {
        $tree = new TestableTreeNode();
        $flatTree = [];
        $id = 0;
        for ($level = 0; $level < $levels; $level++) {
            $treeLevel = [];
            $max = pow(TestableTreeNode::NODE_CHILDREN_MAX, $level+1);
            for ($nodeId = 0; $nodeId < $max; $nodeId++) {
                $treeNode = (new TestableTreeNode())
                    ->setId($id++)
                    ->setName($level . ':' . $nodeId);
                $tree->addChild($treeNode);
                $treeLevel[] = $treeNode;
            }
            $flatTree[] = $treeLevel;
        }
        return (object)['flat' => $flatTree, 'real' => $tree];
    }

    protected function flatten(TestableTreeNode $treeNode, $level = 0)
    {
        if (!$level) {
            $this->flatStorage = [];
        }
        foreach ($treeNode->getChildren() as $child) {
            $this->setRendered($level, $child);
            $this->flatten($child, $level+1);
        }
        return $this->flatStorage;
    }

    protected function setRendered($level, $child)
    {
        if (!isset($this->flatStorage[$level])) {
            $this->flatStorage[$level] = [];
        }
        $this->flatStorage[$level][] = $child;
    }

    private function dump($fileName, $data)
    {
        ob_start();
        var_dump($data);
        file_put_contents($fileName, ob_get_contents());
        ob_end_clean();
    }

}
```

[Code in action(with unit-test)](http://runnable.com/VLxM1SfZfhAs0_EW/n-dimensional-tree-for-php)

Comment: What does the tree do? Is this a nested set plugin for Doctrine? What do you mean by deciding "which node should be chosen on addition"? How far does your code sample above do what you want?

Comment: @halfer No it's not for doctrine, tree is just tree I need store some data in it. I meant: which of child nodes I should select and run `TreeNode#addChild` on it, cause if I choose first one tree won't be tree it became just list. So I need to find out an algorithm based on which I'll be able to control recursion. Currently I have very poor results :( Previously nodes added based on weight(some internal var to observe for tree size): add node to smallest one.

Comment: In your 2 dimensional example, I guess you get a count for all items (2-1) levels in, and add the item to the first node that doesn't have MAX items. I'm not sure how to do this efficiently though, other than maybe separately holding a reference to the next add location.

Comment: I don't know your overall purpose, but does Doctrine have a hierarchy plugin that will simplify this?

Comment: @halfer It is not 2 dimensional, it is infinite, doctrine plugin is unsuitable, cause addition in it is fully manual and it is limited with max child 2 nodes. I think loading all of the table is at least bad idea... Problem of saving reference to next suitable node is: it changes too often and in any case should be computed somehow(and it is the QUESTION :) )

Comment: Your example is 2 dimensional, as far as I can tell. I understand that it can be of any number of dimensions in practice.

Comment: @halfer Have a pity on me, I can't write from 0 to infinite) It's just an example, in database I already have 6000 rows and it grows...

Comment: It wasn't a criticism, @smt. The point I was making is that you need to search (dimensions-1) to find whether a node is full.

Comment: @halfer If it was just one dimensional, I'd rather  used an array, not custom tree(also I'd be the happiest coder in the world). I've changed `Obj` to `TreeNode`, hope it would help

Comment: (The other thing you can do to make this more answerable is to make it runnable (i.e. take out the Doctrine stuff) and put a link onto a live codepad, so people can fork and experiment. If you add that I will cast a reopen vote. Seems to me that if you don't want to hold a separate "next node location" reference you will need to do a recursive search of the tree for every add).

Comment: @halfer Recursive search through tree is not bad idea, but it have to be limited.

Comment: (`limited to N nodes in level` sounds off, _N-ary_ (`limited to N descendants per node`) familiar. `N-dimensional tree` reminds of [search trees for data with multidimensional keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)) `. (The project will fail if purpose isn't documented - facilitates asking answerable questions, too.) OO is about modeling objects and actions of the problem domain in (the public side of) the implementation domain. Keep a count of the descendants of a node, add to the leftmost node with the lowest count.

Comment: @greybeard As you can see previous version was based on your comment, but it is not what I need. Also K-D tree is not what I need, cause K-D is binary tree.

Comment: `As you can see` - without a specification what attribute `weight` is to hold, your readers are left to their own devices. Without removals and other constraints on placing new nodes, `addChild()` seems trivial: take the n-ary representation of the (old) total number of nodes in the tree; from most significant digit to least but one, follow the correspondent reference; insert according to last digit. Corner cases left as an exercise …

Comment: @greybeard It is not trivial! I need to add nodes LEFT-TO-RIGHT(firstly fill in first node, then second, then third, then children of first, then children of second, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Found out solution, it is not the most elegant(I think), but it works. Shortly: it is based on maximum allowed nodes per level. Also updated code in *runnable*, code is passing unit-test.

```
<?php

class TreeNode
{
    const NODE_CHILDREN_MAX = 3;
    const NODE_CHILD_LEVELS_MAX = 6;

    protected $id;

    private $parent;

    private $children = [];

    private $weight = 0;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set weight
     *
     * @param integer $weight
     * @return TreeNode
     */
    public function setWeight($weight)
    {
        $this->weight = $weight;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get weight
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getWeight()
    {
        return $this->weight;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param TreeNode $parent
     * @return TreeNode
     */
    public function setParent(TreeNode $parent = null)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return TreeNode
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * Add children
     *
     * @param TreeNode $node
     * @return TreeNode[]
     */
    public function addChild(TreeNode $node)
    {
        if (count($this->children) < static::NODE_CHILDREN_MAX) {
            $this->children[] = $node;
            $node->setParent($this);
            $this->weight++;
            return [$this, $node];
        } else {
            $children = $this->children;
            $targetWeight = $this->getTargetChildWeight();
            $children = array_filter($children, function (TreeNode $node) use ($targetWeight) {
                return $node->weight < $targetWeight;
            });
            usort($children, function (TreeNode $node1, TreeNode $node2) use ($targetWeight) {
                $sorting = (($targetWeight - $node1->weight) - ($targetWeight - $node2->weight)) % 2;
                if (!$sorting) {
                    $sorting = ($node1->weight - $node2->weight) % 2;
                    if (!$sorting) {
                        $sorting = ($node1->id - $node2->id) % 2;
                    }
                }
                return $sorting;
            });
            foreach ($children as $childNode) {
                $this->weight++;
                return array_merge($childNode->addChild($node), [$this]);
            }
            return [];
        }
    }

    private function getTargetChildWeight()
    {
        $levels = array_map(function (TreeNode $node) {
            return $node->getChildLevelCount();
        }, $this->children);
        return static::weightOf(min($levels));
    }

    /**
     * Get children
     *
     * @return TreeNode[]
     */
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    public function getChildLevelCount()
    {
        return static::levelOf($this->weight);
    }

    public static function weightOf($level)
    {
        if (!$level) {
            return 0;
        }
        return pow(self::NODE_CHILDREN_MAX, $level) + static::weightOf($level-1);
    }

    public static function levelOf($weight)
    {
        $level = 0;
        while (static::weightOf($level) < $weight) {
            $level++;
        }
        if (static::weightOf($level) == $weight) {
            $level++;
        }
        return $level;
    }
}
```